# show hide works only for first time in ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a div to show/hide on click and this div will load content from me.html via ajax load. I am adding a class class added to this a tag and then when I click again on a tag with added class, it should hide the div. But this doesn't work.

```
$(function() {
    $("#nav a").click(function() { 
        $(this).toggleClass('added');
        if($(".o1").length <= 0) { 
            $("body").append('<div class="o1"></div>');
            $(".o1").load("me.html").css("display","block");
        }
        $(".added").click(function() { 
            $(".o1").css("display","none");
        })
    });
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What errors did you get?

Comment: no errors, looks like logic isn't proper

Comment: @Jack: what should it be then.

Comment: @Mike probably just $(this).click(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. This will setup the object if it doesn't exist. Then once it does it will toggle it if for future clicks.

```
$(function() {
    $("#nav a").click(function() { 
        $(this).toggleClass('added');
        if($(".o1").length <= 0)
        { 
            $("body").append('<div class="o1"></div>');
            $(".o1").load("me.html");
        } else if($(this).hasClass("added"))
            $(".o1").hide();
        } else {
            $(".o1").show();
        }
    });
});
```

Adding a `click` handler to all `.added` links with your code would create a problem, because in your code you have.

This shows the timeline of what is happening. Hope you can follow. The numbers in brackets are events. The same number signifies they happen at the same time.

(1) `#nav a` is clicked **then** `#nav a` gets a class of `added` **then** `.o1` is added **then** any link with `added` class gets a click event

(2) `#nav a` is clicked **then** `#nav a` removes class of `added` **then** `.o1` already exists **then** any link with `added` class gets a click event (but not this link, but it still has the previous click event, because it wasn't dettached)

(2) `.added` is also considered clicked at the same time as action above because it was attached during (1)

(3) `#nav a` is clicked **then** `#nav a` gets a class of `added` **then** `.o1` already exists **then** any link with `added` class gets a click event

(3) `.added` is also considered clicked at the same time as action above because it was attached during (1)

(4) `#nav a` is clicked **then** `#nav a` gets a class of `added` **then** `.o1` already exists **then** any link with `added` class gets a click event

(4) `.added` is also considered clicked at the same time as action above because it was attached during (1)
(4) `.added` is also considered clicked at the same time as action above because it was attached during (3)

etc ...

The key thing to grasp is you are not detaching `click` events, instead you are attaching more and more.

Comment: @Mike There is nothing in your code to toggle the state after it is hidden. I have updated my code to work with your `added` class.

Comment: @Mike have updated with a timeline of events, to maybe explain whats going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
<div class="o1"></div>

$(".o1").hide();

$(function() {

    $("#nav a").click(function() { 

            $(this).toggleClass('added');


            if($(this).hasClass('added') == false){ 

                    $(".o1").load("me.html", function(){$(".o1").show()});

                }

            if($(this).hasClass('added') == true){ 

                    $(".o1").hide();

                })
      });
});
```